# Finding longest sequence of consecutive repeats of a substring within a string

Tags: python

My code for the function is really messy and I cannot find why it returns a list of 1's. A solution would obviously be great, but with advice to make the code just better, i'd be happy

```
def cont_cons_repeats(ADN, STR, pos):
slong = 0
# Find start of sequence
for i in range(len(ADN[pos:])):
    if ADN[pos + i:i + len(STR)] == STR:
        slong = 1
        pos = i + pos
        break

if slong == 0:
    return 0

# First run
for i in range(len(ADN[pos:])):
    i += len(STR) - 1
    if ADN[pos + i + 1:pos + i + len(STR)] == STR:
        slong += 1
    else:
        pos = i + pos
        break
    
# Every other run
while True:
    pslong = cont_cons_repets(ADN, STR, pos)
    if pslong > slong:
        slong = pslong
    if pslong == 0:
        break

return slong
```

(slong stands for size of longest sequence, pslong for potential slong, and pos for position)

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you provided sample input data and your expected output.

Comment: Do you have some sample data that others can run through your function. Have you tried regular expressions? https://regex101.com ?

Comment: What is the point of passing in `pos`? Do you only want to find the longest run of consecutive repeats of `STR` in `ADN` at or after `pos`?

Comment: @Grismar I thought it would be necessary for the function to be recursive

Comment: @Nick ADN is a big chunck of DNA (a .txt with one long line), the STRs are sequences of 4 to 8 nucleotides (i. e. AGATC, AATG, etc). The expected output would be in one case ['2', '8', '3'] (this is all part of a problem from cs50, should've said that in the post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you pass in `pos` because you want to ignore the start of the string you're searching up to `pos`:

```
def longest_run(text, part, pos):
    m = 0
    n = 0
    while pos < len(text):
        if text[pos:pos+len(part)] == part:
            n += 1
            pos += len(part)
        else:
            m = max(n, m)
            n = 0
            pos += 1
    return m
```

You say your function returns a list of 1s, but that doesn't seem to match what your code is doing. Your provided code has some syntax errors, including a misspelled call to your function `cont_cons_repets`, so it's impossible to say why you're getting that result.

You mentioned in the comments that you thought a recursive solution was required. You could definitely make it work as a recursive function, but in many cases where a recursive function works, you should consider a non-recursive function to save on resources. Recursive functions can be very elegant and easy to read, but remember that *any* recursive function can also be written as a non-recursive function. It's never required, often more resource-intensive, but sometimes just a very clean and easy to maintain solution.

Comment: I changed the name of the function for the post (comments and names were in spanish), and mispelled it the second time haha. Your code worked, thanks!